# Session attributes are null when running from remote server

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

When I retrieve Session attributes in my servlet on my local machine they return fine. However when I do this same thing on a remote server they return null and throw a null pointer exception.

Setting the session attributes

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {      


        HttpSession sess = request.getSession();

        String categoryID = request.getParameterValues("category");
        sess.setAttribute("category",categoryID);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Questions.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);


}
```

Retrieving the session attributes

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {


    HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
    String categories = (String) sess.getAttribute("category");
```

My web.xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/LabInspection</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
  <session-config>
   <session-timeout>600</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Are you using web.xml? If m not wrong, theres something like `<session-timeout>20</session-timeout>` that needs to be set. Unfortunately I dont recollect it properly, but I'd look into setting session in web.xml if i was you.

Comment: I have added a session timeout to my web.xml, but it has not changed my error. @ajc